# Wrap every 5 items in jQuery for each

Tags: jquery

I am trying to group elements inside foreach loop. I couldn't figured it yet.

```
$select.children('option.active,option.enabled').each(function(i, option) {

        var $option = jQuery(option),
            selectId = $option.parent('select').attr('id');

        $variationItems.find('input[type="radio"]')
        .filter('[name="'+selectId+'"]')
        .filter('[value="'+option.value+'"]')
        .parents('.mspc-variation:first').show()

        $variationItems.find('input[type="checkbox"]')
        .filter('[name="'+selectId+'"]')
        .filter('[value="'+option.value+'"]')
        .parents('.mspc-variation:first').show()

        if( i <= 5 ){

            $variationItems.wrapAll('<div class="grouped-section-1"/>');

        }else if ( i <= 10) {

            $variationItems.wrapAll('<div class="grouped-section-2"/>');
        } else if ( i <= 15 ) {

            $variationItems.wrapAll('<div class="grouped-section-3"/>');
        }


    });
```

$select.children('option.active,option.enabled') this gives an array of elements and I wanna wrap each 5 items by

```
<div class="section-row"></div>
```

Really appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20188199/jquery-wrap-first-n-number-of-elements-into-one-new-elements-and-rest-n-into-ano shows how to wrap into just two groups, it should be easy to extrapolate that to a loop for all the elements.